# How to simplify: $f(x)=(2^a-1)(3^a-1)(4^a-1)...(x^a-1)\mod {m}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to simplify $f(x)$ for positive integers $a,m,x$ where $x>1$ and $m$ is a composition of two very large primes, such that factoring $m$ is not an option. $a$ is relatively small number that doesn't have common divider with $m$

$f(x)=(2^a-1)(3^a-1)(4^a-1)...(x^a-1)\mod {m}$

I have been trying to play with small numbers to see how this expression looks like and come with below examples, my goal is to be able to solve this for big numbers of $x$, at the moment I can only solve this recursively.

$$f(3)=(2^a-1)(3^a-1)=$$
$$-2^a - 3^a + 6^a + 1$$

---

$$f(4)=(2^a-1)(3^a-1)(4^a-1)=$$
$$2^a + 3^a + 4^a - 6^a - 8^a - 12^a + 24^a - 1$$

---

$$f(5)=(2^a-1)(3^a-1)(4^a-1)(5^a-1)=$$
$$-2^a - 3^a - 4^a - 5^a + 6^a + 8^a + 10^a + 12^a + 15^a + 20^a - 24^a - 30^a - 40^a - 60^a + 120^a + 1$$

Comment: Please note that your headline and the actual text differ

Comment: @ReinerMartin fixed

Comment: This will in many cases be 0 mod m (for $x\ge m$ for example), since only one of the $(n+x)^a$ terms has to be one for that.

Comment: @ReinerMartin good point, in my experiments I am actually looking at $a> n+x$, so I updated the question to include it. But then I never saw it become 0, I try to search for it.

Comment: Do you have any condition on $m$ in mind? Also note that because of Euler's theorem only the residue of $a \mod \varphi(m)$ matters.

Comment: @ReinerMartin yeah, I explain my idea in more details in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531661/found-a-function-for-factoring-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

This expression will be $0 \mod m\;$ in specific cases, for example if $x\ge m,$ because then one of the terms $n+i$ will be 1 $\pmod m,$ or if $a$ is a multiple of the Euler phi function $\varphi(m),$ because then $(n+i)^a\equiv 1 \pmod m$ for all $i.$